# What kind of technique is Madara using?

Tags: naruto

In the episode that shows us the battle between Madara and Hashirama in the Valley Of The End, during an "exchange" of techniques, a peculiar one is being used by Madara. Mainly, after fending off a shuriken(?) his tomoe start spinning and the time seems to rewind to the point where the shuriken was being thrown in the first place. This was the only time I noticed this technique being used, and it looks like no other, apart from Izanagi, which it cannot be, for it would void his eye. 
[The exact moment of usage](https://youtu.be/UEmJZJ94XkY?t=3m17s)

Comment: It might be his sharingan's specific ability.

Comment: I assume it is the sharingans ability to read the opponents attack and the movement of other objects. ether they decided to show it like this this time or madara is just using it more efficiently, it is the same ability in all the sharingans

Comment: Not sure about the source, but [this link](http://www.leafninja.com/uchiha.php) might help you

Comment: @Bhagyesh I scanned through the information in that link, it seems to get several things wrong. Things like Madara stealing Izuna's eyes, and Sasuke's mangekyou actually being Itachi's, both of which are flat out wrong statements. There are several more examples of incorrect statments, that link is at best very outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Madara is foreshadowing where how the shuriken will hit him. This is one of the powers a sharingan gives. So during the fight he foreshadows that the shuriken will hit him so he avoids it when it actually does happen.

Comment: It's almost similar to how kakashi fought with Zabuza, he can copy each and every jutsu in parallel. Kakashi foreseen zabuza's hand seals and copied them.

Comment: @krishna-Itachi'sfan The sharingan at best slows down time for the perception of the user, allowing them to better read the opponents moves. If you master this, then imitating their moves an instant after they make them is possible. It does not show you the future, but it can help you predict it.

Comment: as for the answer, His eye spins after he dodges the shuriken, and it then zooms in on Hashirama right before it was thrown, where it reveals that Hashirama did not throw the shuriken, but a tree branch did, and that other tree branches had picked up the rest of the weapons he just summoned. This is the opposite of foreshadowing in any meaning of the word. He saw the past from a different point of view, revealing crucial information.